# XML/KML not well formed

Tags: python, xml, kml

I'm trying to parse a KML service using the following:

```
import requests
import responses
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
response = requests.get('http://206.74.144.42/eitms/roadconditions/')
data = str(response.content)
tree = ET.fromstring(data)
```

but it keeps telling me that the XML is 'not well formed' like so:

```
not well-formed (invalid token): line 1, column 1
```

what does this mean and how do I fix it? Using Python 3.6.

Comment: Why are you using `data[1:]`?  If you're stripping off the first character because it's a quote, presumably you would need to strip off the last character because it is also a quote.  Perhaps that's what it is complaining about.

Comment: The first character is a 'b' that's why

Comment: If you mean it looks like `b'something'`, the `b` is not actually part of the string.

Comment: it does look like that, but even using the `data` it produces the same result. @JohnGordon see the updated question.

Comment: I tried running your code myself.  If you call `fromstring(response.content)` directly, without converting it with `str()`, it works.

Comment: that worked John, would you like to add that as an answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call `fromstring(response.content)` directly, without converting it with `str()`.